# Want to remove default border from my background img

Tags: html, image, css

How do I take this ugly `1px black border` away from this background image??

I uncheck `background: url( ../images/thumbsDownSelected-Red.png);` in the Chrome web developer tools and all that remains is this ugly 1px solid black border.

```
.thumbsUpSelected {
  background: url( ../images/thumbsUpSelected-Green.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

<img src=""  id="" class=" thumbsUpSelected thumbs-button ">
```

I've tried removing `src=""`, nothing changed.

Even telling `img{border:0 !important}` does nothing!

I'm not looking to reference the img in the src= so avoid posting solutions that do that pls.

What's going on?? Why is there a mythical border that doesn't show up in dev tools and can't be removed??

Comment: can you prepare a fiddle or post full code/url.

Comment: what about borders on the div?

Comment: Will the ugly 1px solid black border go away if you don't load the background?

Comment: I made a mistake by saying i loaded the img in a div. i had loaded it in an img and the empty src="" was what caused this ugly border to appear. Changing it to a div is what fixed it. Upvoting all of you. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

`border: none;`

on the div?

It's the div that has the border. The image is just the div's background, so you take that away the border on the div will remain. I'm assuming the div has the border from some other css (probably thumbs-button?). In which case you'll need to put !important or change the other class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it

the empty  tag defaults this border.

simply changing the img tag to a div fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.thumbsUpSelected 
{
border: none;
}
```